# Change string by index

Tags: c++, string

I am a beginner in C++ and I am currently working with strings.

My question is why when compiling the code I'm providing below, I can get the string's characters when I use index notation, but cannot get the string itself using `cout`?

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string original; // original message
    string altered; // message with letter-shift

    original = "abc";
    cout << "Original : " << original << endl; // display the original message

    for(int i = 0; i<original.size(); i++)
        altered[i] = original[i] + 5;

    // display altered message
    cout << altered[0] << " " << altered[1] << " " << altered[2] << endl;
    cout << "altered : " << altered << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the characters in the string `altered` are displayed correctly with this line:

```
cout << altered[0] << " " << altered[1] << " " << altered[2] << endl;
```

But the string itself is not displayed with this line:

```
cout << "altered : " << altered << endl;
```

I would like to know why this happens.

Comment: While you already have an answer below, try to find out how to enable diagnostics in your program. The code you have is indeed buggy, but using the diagnostic mode that C++ compilers provide, that error could have been detected easily.

Comment: Please go through all the answers now and mark the one that best answers your question. It's not good to leave a question open :-)

Comment: Please, note that the C++ code are not [*scripts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) but *source code*. Scripts are interpreted and C++ source code is [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not resized your `altered` string to fit the length of the `original` string before the loop, thus your code exhibits *undefined behavior*:

```
altered[i] = original[i] + 5; // UB -  altered is empty
```

To fix this, resize `altered` before the loop:

```
altered.resize(original.size());
```

Or use `std::string::operator+=` or similar to append to `altered`:

```
altered += original[i] + 5;
```

This way, it can be empty before the loop, it will automatically resize itself to contain appended characters.

---

## Explanation

The way UB is happening here, is that you're succeeding in writing the data in the static array, which `std::string` uses for short string optimization (`std::string::operator[]` does no checks if you're accessing this array past the `std::string::size()`), but `std::string::size()` remains `0`, as well as `std::string::begin() == std::string::end()`.

That's why you can access the data individually (again, with UB):

```
cout << altered[0] << " " << altered[1] << " " << altered[2] << endl;
```

but `cout << aligned` does not print anything, considering **simplified** `operator<<` definition for `std::string` looks **functionally** like this:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::string const& str)
{
    for(auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) // this loop does not run
        os << *it;

    return os;
}
```

In one sentence, **`std::string` is not aware of what you did to its underlying array and that you meant the string to grow in length.**

---

**To conclude, `<algoritm>` way of doing this transformation:**

```
std::transform(original.begin(), original.end(),
    std::back_inserter(altered), // or altered.begin() if altered was resized to original's length
    [](char c)
    {
        return c + 5;
    }
```

(required headers: `<algorithm>`, `<iterator>`)

Comment: or you can add altered.resize( original.size() ); before for.

Comment: @LogicStuff I deleted my objection, it's perfectly reasonable for this small context. I would add to the answer that what you are doing with += is string concatenation which the OP way not be familiar with. You have described the problem perfectly, and the solution is fine, just not explained why it solves the problem you have identified. I can edit it for you if you want.

Comment: I can do it myself, no problem. It's just that I was more anxious to explain the behavior.

Comment: @AntonTodua, you could, but why would you? It would be much easier and cleaner to read and reason about, to actually initialise `altered` as a copy of `original`. In fact, the two first lines could be changed to: `string original = "abc"` `string altered = abc` and then iterate through `altered`, increasing the ascii value of each char. The would be the straightforward alternative to LogicStuff's answer. I still think his choice of concatenating variants on each char in `original` is actually nicer than my approach, though.

Comment: @dep0 Sorry, I forgot to reply, yes, both times correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your program string `altered` is empty. It has no elements.
Thus you may not use the subscript operator to access non-existent elements of the string as you are doing

```
 altered[i] = original[i] + 5;
```

So you can append the string with new characters. There are several ways to do this. For example

```
 altered.push_back( original[i] + 5 );
```

or

```
 altered.append( 1, original[i] + 5 );
```

or

```
 altered += original[i] + 5;
```

As you may not apply the subscript operator for an empty string to assign a value then it is better to use the range-based for loop because the index itself in fact is not used. For example

```
for ( char c : original ) altered += c + 5;
```

Comment: @BenjaminR There is no any need to use reference for type char. Without reference the code can be even more efficient.

Comment: @BenjaminR You do not understand how compilers generate object code.

Comment: @BenjaminR Look yourself what object code will be generated.

Answer (score 2):

The size of `altered` is always zero - by using indexes you are trying to copy values from `original` to `altered` at indexes `altered` does not *have*. As LogicStuff has said, this is undefined behaviour - it doesn't generate an error because when we use indexes with `std::string` we are in fact calling an operator on a `std::string` to access the `data` field of a string. Using `[]` operator is defined in the C++ Standard as having **no range check** - that's why no error was thrown. The *safe* way to access indexes is to use the `at(i)` method: `altered.at(i)` will instead throw a **range error** if `altered.size() <= i`

However, I'm going to give this as my solution because it's a "Modern C++" approach (plus shorter and complete).

This is the alternative I would do to what has been given above:

```
string original = "abc";
string altered = original;
for (auto& c : altered) c += 5;  // ranged for-loop - for each element in original, increase its value by 5
cout << altered << endl;
```

Note the significant reduction in code :-)

Even if I were doing it LogicStuff's way, I would still do it like this:

```
string original = "abc"
string altered = ""; // this is actually what an empty string should be initialised to.
for (auto c : original) altered += (c+5);
```

However, I actually don't recommend this approach, because of the way `push_back()` and string appending / string concatenation work. It's fine in this small example, but what if `original` was a string holding the first 10 pages of a book to be parsed? Or what if it's a raw input of a million characters? Then every time the `data` field for `altered` reaches its limit it needs to be re-allocated via a system call and the contents of `altered` are copied and the prior allocation for the `data` field is freed. This is a significant performance impediment which grows relative to the size of `original` -- it's just bad practice. It would always be more efficient to do a complete copy and then iterate, making the necessary adjustments on the copied string. The same applies to `std::vector`.